# How to find a mistake in the calculation of the amounts

Tags: c++, math

I tried to complete a task with the calculation of the amounts. The task is Sn=(cosx/1)+((cosx+cos2x)/2)+...+((cosx+...+cosxn)/n);x - float, n - integer.
But the programm outputed zero in every situation.

Its c++ code written on DevC++5.11. I almost finished the code, but i cant find a mistake.

```
float funct(float x, float s, int n)
{
    if (n < 1) {
        cout << s;
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = n; i < 1; i--) {
        float a = (cos(i * x)) / n;
        s = s + a;
    }
    return funct(x, s, n - 1);
}

int main(void)
{
    float x = 1, s = 0;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    funct(x, s, n);
}
```

I expect the output something like terible float numbers, but the actual output is zero.

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger yet?

Comment: `for(int i=n;i<1;` - that's not going to loop very often...

Comment: Should not be `s` passed by reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = n; i < 1; i--)
```

Should be

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
```

if you want it to loop from 1 to n

Comment: Or `i > 1` if you if you intend to count down until the base case.